# Error passing secret to reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to call a reusable workflow.

https://github.com/dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/blob/master/.github/workflows/instance-manager.yaml

The caller looks like the following

```
name: Tests, build and deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - feature/**
    tags:
      - v*.*.*

  pull_request:

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/.github/workflows/instance-manager.yaml@v0.2.0
    with:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: dhis2/instance-manager-api
      PROCESS_NAME: dhis2-instance-manager
      DOCKER_USERNAME: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}"
      DOCKER_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}"
      SOPS_KMS_ARN: "${{ secrets.SOPS_KMS_ARN }}"
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"
      KUBECONFIG: "${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}"
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Invalid workflow file
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/cicd.yaml (Line: 21, Col: 24): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME .github/workflows/cicd.yaml (Line: 22, Col: 24): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD
```

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong? Also please let me know if I should post more code

Comment: Can you try moving the environment variable definitions from the action definition to before your job under `env:`? Feels like the parameters are just placed wrong. Also I thing you can drop the quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The caller had secrets under "with", should be under "secrets"

###### Calls Workflow

```
...
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/.github/workflows/instance-manager.yaml@v0.2.0
    with:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: dhis2/instance-manager-api
      PROCESS_NAME: dhis2-instance-manager
    secrets:
      DOCKER_USERNAME: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}"
      DOCKER_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}"
      SOPS_KMS_ARN: "${{ secrets.SOPS_KMS_ARN }}"
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"
      KUBECONFIG: "${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}"
```

###### Called Workflow

```
...
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      DOCKER_USERNAME:
        required: true
        description: ''
```

Comment: That doesn't work: `The workflow is not valid. Unexpected value 'secrets'`

Comment: It works just fine when I use it. Your indentation is probably off or something else is causing your workflow to be invalid.

Comment: @Vasily, I too had that error until I put the variable in quotes like in the answer.

Comment: An important trick here is to keep them the same name `DOCKER_USERNAME` -> `{{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}` and no other name.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this error for a while. The problem for me was that the reusable workflow needs to declare the secrets that are passed to it. More information [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callsecrets).

So, for this example, you must have the following on the called workflow:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      DOCKER_USERNAME:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
      DOCKER_PASSWORD:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
      SOPS_KMS_ARN:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
      KUBECONFIG:
        description: 'some description'
        required: true
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Github actions you can pass all the secrets from the calling workflow to the called workflow with the `inherit` keyword.

#### Calling Workflow

```
...
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/.github/workflows/instance-manager.yaml@v0.2.0
    with:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: dhis2/instance-manager-api
      PROCESS_NAME: dhis2-instance-manager
    secrets: inherit
```

#### Called Workflow

```
...
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:
        required: true
        type: string
...
env: 
  DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
  DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use own secrets

```
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/.github/workflows/instance-

    manager.yaml@v0.2.0
        with:
          DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: dhis2/instance-manager-api
          PROCESS_NAME: dhis2-instance-manager
        secrets:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}"
```

But you can also use workflow own secrets with inherition with

### implicitly pass the secrets

**secrets: inherit**

```
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: dhis2-sre/gha-workflows/.github/workflows/instance-manager.yaml@v0.2.0
    with:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: dhis2/instance-manager-api
      PROCESS_NAME: dhis2-instance-manager
    secrets: inherit
```