# Github Actions error - secret is not defined in the referenced workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am calling a child workflow in repo 2 from a parent workflow in repo 1

**Calling Workflow**

```
jobs:
 download_secure_file:
   name: Download Secure File
   uses: MyOrg/BuildTemplates/.github/workflows/template-download-secure-file.yml@main
   secrets:
     CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
     CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
     CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
```

**Called Workflow**

```
name: DownloadSecureFile

on:
  workflow_call:
    outputs:
      secure_file:
        value: ${{ jobs.download_secure_file.outputs.file }}
    secrets:
      CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_CLIENT_ID:
        required: true
      CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_TENANT_ID:
        required: true
      CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID:
        required: true
env:
  AZURE_KEYVAULT_NAME: 'kv-rtl-sma-prod'
  AZURE_SECRET_NAME: 'keys'
```

The called workflow is in a different repo within the same organisation. Secrets are kept at the organisation level.

I get the below error:

```
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main.yml#L37
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 37, Col: 38): Invalid secret, CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_CLIENT_ID is not defined in the referenced workflow. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 38, Col: 38): Invalid secret, CSSM_HW_FOODS_AZURE_TENANT_ID is not defined in the referenced workflow.
```

It would really be great to understand what I am doing wrong here. Have been trying to find a solution for the past few days. I have gone through the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493352/error-passing-secret-to-reusable-workflow) which is same as what I have done.

Do I raise this as an issue with Github Actions?

Comment: Does the error refer to the caller workflow, or the called workflow? Does the calling repository have access to these two secrets?

Comment: The error refers to the calling workflow. Yes - both calling and the called repositories have access to these organisation secrets. I have triple checked this by running pipelines in both these repositories stand-alone